# Probabilities problem

Tags: probability, statistics

A flower seller has flowers with leaves of mean length $1.53\,\mathrm{cm}$ and variance $0.04\,\mathrm{cm}^2$. If he has $200$ flowers and he knows flowers with leaf length $< 1\,\mathrm{cm}$ won't be sold, then how many flowers will he sell?
I've tried to do this with $P(Z< )$ but I don't know what to put between brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to compute the standard deviation from the variance you are given, then to compute how many standard deviations low of the mean a flower has to be before it doesn't sell.  Look up that number of standard deviations in your z-score table.